# copying data from local machine to VM

Tags: virtualbox

I have a windows 8.1 machine and linux is installed as VM, can anyone let me know how to copy data from local desktop to VM?

Answer (score 0):

The Simple and the best is to use the Pendrive/ USB Storage device and select the USB devices in the virtual box.
When you select your USB device it will be works for linux, 
If deselect 
then it works for Windows as well.

Hope your problem is solved...

Answer (score 0):

Many ways are possible, here is a sampling:

- set up a shared folder using guest additions
- use a thumb drive
- utilize cloud services such as Dropbox
- local network shares